# XCode's Default Colors

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm curious why in XCode `Text(...)` (which is a `frozen struct`) is displayed purple, yet other structs are not?

Furthermore, why is `Text(...)` the same color as `View` (a protocol)?

Is there a way to write a struct that is colored purple in XCode?

Screenshot w. code attached.

[image: Code photo]

Answer (score 1):

The color parser does not distinguish a struct from a protocol. `View` and `Text` are both being parsed by the color parser under the category Other Type Names (as you can readily see for yourself by looking in the Themes preference).

`MyCustomText()` is something you declared, so it falls under Project Type Names. The actual declaration `struct MyCustomText` falls under Type Declarations.

Feel free to pick a different theme or modify an existing theme, but you cannot create parse categories that do not exist.